# French drain issue

Tags: french-drain

My downspout would always overflow. After removing the coupler I see the pipe that goes underground to the French drain is sitting on the footing with a smaller hole on its side to push water to the drain

That hole is smaller so when it rains hard the pipe overflows

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Had  to look up *'French drain'*... *'<insert country here> word'* is very localised, but in the opposite way of what you would initially think :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to enlarge the hole, but not to anything larger than the pipe or french drain's channel or trough.

You can (possibly) use a drill with a hole-saw (i.e. for door locks), an oscillating cutter tool or best and cheapest is a pencil or stick Soldering Iron (assuming everything's plastic) from the trough side.

Ultimately, if you can, you may be best served in lifting and prying out the whole french drain to properly re-do the trough end and pipe connection.